# Incrementing shortcut

Tags: python

I am new to Python an am having an issue understanding a concept.

So if:

```
spam = spam + 1
```

is the same as

```
spam += 1
```

Why would I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

when running this code?:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for loot in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(loot, 0) 
        inventory = inventory[loot] + 1
    return inventory
```

Shouldn't

```
inventory = inventory[loot] + 1
```

be the same as

```
inventory[loot] +=1
```

?

Comment: `inventory` here appears to be a dict. when you do `inventory[loot] +1` you take an ITEM from the list and add 1 to it, you are adding to INTs together and overwriting inventory. also, `inventory[loot] +=1` expands to `inventory[loot] = inventory[loot] + 1`

Comment: You may think about using a defaultdict rather than using `setdefault` every time in the loop https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Thanks @Nullman. I thought I tried that...now I feel silly

Comment: and @user1558604 I will take a look at that, but it defaultdict I do not think has been covered yet

Comment: Strictly speaking, `spam += 1` is equivalent to `spam.__iadd__(1)`. For *some* types, that may behave the same as `spam = spam + 1` (which is equivalent to `spam.__add__(1)`), but not all types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `inventory = inventory[loot] + 1` you are changing `inventory` to the value of `inventory[loot] + 1`, an int, so in the next iteration you are doing `int.setdefault(loot, 0)`. To change the value you need to use

```
inventory[loot] = inventory[loot] + 1
```

This is the equivalent of

```
inventory[loot] += 1
```

You can also skip the `setdefault()`

```
def add_to_inventory(addedItems):
    inventory = {}
    for loot in addedItems:
        inventory[loot] = 1
    return inventory

d = add_to_inventory(added_items)
```

Comment: Thanks @Guy! When I was testing all the combinations to try and figure out why it wasn't working I thought I had tried that one. Appreciate the help.